# Confusion about Resource loader, ClassLoader, inputStream, Loading and writing files in general

Tags: java, package, resources, classloader

In one of my exercises, the text recommended to use the Resource loader, what is it?

My researches pointed toward ClassLoader.getResources() and this.getClass().getResources(); I assume it's something that searches the package for the file specified but how, and what are the differences between the two methods?

Can't I just make an InputStream with an absolute path and navigate in the package to where my files are?

Comment: Java resources are embedded in your application. They are loaded from the class-path. That means they need to be loaded in a location-independent way; using an absolute path would defeat that purpose. As for, `Class::getResource` and `ClassLoader::getResource`, they are similar in many ways. But the former method can take "relative" (to the class's package) or absolute resource names, whereas the latter method can only accept absolute resource names. There's also some module-related access differences and such, but I assume that's a little beyond what you need to know for your exercise.

Comment: That all said, "resource loader" is not really a standard library thing. Does your exercise involve using some kind of framework? For instance, Spring has a [`ResourceLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) interface.

Comment: No framework, "Use the resource loader to load the file provided in res.
  You can wrap the stream with a `StreamReader` and a `BufferedReader` to get the contents and proceed line by line." that's what the exercise says... (ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(configFile) this is the solution, the input is a String so i assume is just the file name, but then i don't understand the path thing, the file is located in the resource folder ( src/main/resources ) the gradle standard, is it a standard search location?

Comment: I think you need to ask your teachers what they meant.  Slaw has given you his best guess (and  I concur) ... but only your teachers know for sure what the "Use the resource loader ..." means.  Ask >>them<<.

Comment: for example, giving "ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(configFile)" what would be the path(configFile) to reach config.yml ( src/main/java/my.package.file ; src/main/resources/config.yml)

Comment: *"Can't I just make an `InputStream` with an absolute path and navigate in the package to where my files are?"* - No.  Assuming that your teacher is using "resource loader" as meaning loading from the classpath ... at runtime the resource could be in a ZIP or JAR file (or indeed anything) and navigating to "where the files are" is tricky.

Comment: `src/main/resources` is a "resource root", just like how `src/main/java` is a "source root". You can determine the path from there. For example, if you have a resource at `src/main/resources/com/example/foo.txt`, then the path you'd pass to pass the resource method is `"com/example/foo.txt"` (might need to prefix it with a `/` if you're calling the method on a `Class` object).

Comment: Additionally, want to point out that `StreamReader` is also not a thing in the standard library. There's `InputStreamReader`, which is what I assume is meant, but you'd have to ask whoever gave you the exercise to be sure.

Comment: Or, when the resource is `com/example/foo.txt` and you’re have a `Class` in package `com.example`, you can call `getResource("foo.txt")` on the `Class`